# Regular expression to match string pattern mention

Tags: java, regex, string

I am using java in which I have to check  that input string using regular expression.
 I am newbie to regular expression.

I am entering input in the form .

Following is sample data for which I need to write down regular expression.

```
LastName  FirstName

Ab.CD           BC
Ab-CFgD         Ab.CD
F'b-CF gD       BC
F'b-CF gD.      F.b-CF gD'D
Fb-CF gD'D      BC
F.b-CF gD'D     F'b-CF gD
```

Means It contain `dot(.), Hiphen(-), And single quotes(')` in between of LastName and First name.

I have wrote down regexx only for "Lastname, first name".

```
"[a-zA-Z]+, *[a-zA-Z]+"
```

What would the regular expression be for find all strings mentioned above table

Comment: Your explanation is incomplete with regard to the examples. It seems you can have spaces in the names (from the sample) and it seems that a comma followed by spaces is the separator of the names, but it isn't formally specified. Good, complete specification is crucial to solve correctly a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: -

```
"([a-zA-Z.'-]+),[ ]*([a-zA-Z.'-]+)"
```

**Explanation : -**

```
(            // Capture group 1
  [          // Character class
    a-zA-Z   // alphabets
    .        // a Dot
    '        // A quote
    -        // A hyphen (Should be at the end, in the middle it means a range
  ]+         // Character class close. One or more repetition
)            // Group 1 closes
```

Seems like there is also a space between your lastnames or firstnames, as given in your example. Please check that if it is correct.

You have `two capture groups` in the above regex. Both the groups capture `firstname` and `lastname`. You can print both of them.

A Sample run over some strings: -

```
String str1 = "Ab.CD, Ab.CD";
String str2 = "F'b-CFgD., F'b-CFgD.";
String str3 = "F'b-CF gD, F'b-CF gD";

System.out.println(str1.matches("([a-zA-Z.'-]+),[ ]*([a-zA-Z.'-]+)"));  // true
System.out.println(str2.matches("([a-zA-Z.'-]+),[ ]*([a-zA-Z.'-]+)"));  // true
System.out.println(str3.matches("([a-zA-Z.'-]+),[ ]*([a-zA-Z.'-]+)"));   //false
```

As you can see, last one prints false, as there is a space between your 3rd string. If you want to match space also, then add it to your character class.

---

To make sure that `firstname` and `lastname` start only with letters, you can modify your regex like this: -

```
"([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.'-]+),[ ]*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.'-]+)"
```

Added `[a-zA-Z]` at the start of both the patterns, to make sure the first character is from the given alphabet range.

Comment: Should it check that lastname, firstname is always starts with character not with single quotes, dot and hiphen ?

Comment: @Raje.. You need to modify a little bit. You didn't state that in the question. Will edit the regex.

Comment: There is Comma(,) between LastName, FirstName.

Comment: @Raje.. Edited the Regex for that.

Answer (score 0):

`"([a-zA-Z\\.\\-\\']*),\\s*([a-zA-Z\\.\\-\\']*)"`

Use this web-site to play with regex to figure what will work for you.

[Regex Test Site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: no need to escape `.` in character class..it is treated as literal in character class

Comment: As shown above, no need to escape all these characters in a char class: even the - is safe if it is the last char of the []. Then only \ and ] truly need escaping (and, somehow, " too).